# Is there a reason why $\text{Arg}(z)$ behaves like a logarithm?

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

In school, we learnt how to prove some of the basic properties of $\text{Arg}$, one of them being
$$
\text{Arg}(z_1)+\text{Arg}(z_2)=\text{Arg}(z_1z_2)
$$
We did this by writing $z_1$ and $z_2$ in the modulus-argument form, and using $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$. I noticed that $\text{Arg}(z)$ has a similar property to logarithms, in that
$$
\log a+\log b = \log ab
$$
Is this just a coincidence, or is there a deeper reason for this?

Comment: $r_1e^{ia}r_2e^{ib}=r_1r_2e^{i(a+b)}$

Comment: If this is what your looking for, they are roughly the same $Arg (z)=\theta = \frac{\ln (e^{i \theta})}{i}$

Comment: Its not a coincidence. Try to write down 1) what is the definition of a logarithm and 2) what is the definition of the argument. This will help you see the connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The imaginary part of $\log z$ is $\text{arg}$ z.

$$\log z = \log |z| + i \,\text{arg } z$$

Comment: $\ln(z)=\ln(|z|e^{i\text{Arg}(z)})=\ln |z|+i\, \text{Arg}(z)$

Comment: We could use the notation $\ln z$ or $\log z$ both mean the same thing.  Various textbooks use one or the other.  The notation $\text{Arg }z$ is meant to specify a principal argument, with respect to a principal branch cut.  The notation $\arg z$ works just as well, in this context, but does not specify which branch.  By-the-way, the "principal" branch is also arbitrary.

Comment: @mjw hmm when I was studying, it was the opposite: $\operatorname{Arg}$ meant all branches, while $\arg$ only the primary branch.

Answer (score 1):

Each complex number can be written as
$$z=|z|e^{iArg(z)}$$
$$e^{iArg(z)}=\frac{z}{|z|}$$
$$iArg(z)=\ln(\frac{z}{|z|})$$
$$Arg(z)=-i\ln(\frac{z}{|z|})$$
Looking at this you can see that argument of complex number is closely related to the logarythmic function.

Comment: You have to say that passing from the 2nd to the third line is **only to convey the idea**, because the logarithm (with an "i", pun intended) of a complex number has to be defined, and we know it deserves new definitions (cuts, etc....)

Comment: Yes, loosely speaking the $\ln$ and $Arg$ functions are both commonly defined with a branch cut at negative real numbers ($\theta=\pi$) so that the range of $iArg$ is from $-i\pi$ to $i\pi$ and together with the fact that $\frac{z}{|z|}$ lies on the unit circle, $\ln(\frac{z}{|z|})$ ranges from $-i\pi$ to $i\pi$ too

Comment: This is a nice way of looking at it, starting with the exponential function.