How (or why) do we define $\text{Log}$ in complex nums?
Before I start the question, I’m aware that:
\begin{align}
&\text{Log}(x+yi)=\ln|x+yi|+i\arg(x+yi)
\end{align}
and how it works.
But for me, $\arg$ function seems to be unreasonable… for the value of logarithm. What I’m saying is, why would we state the argument of the complex number to be an imaginary parts?
It’s often used in some series(Taylor, Fourier, …) and it seems even more questionable to me. Why does it works?
I’ll show you an example case that made me feel complex.
\begin{align}
& \textbf{Methods frequently used in Fourier Series} \\
&-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n!} \\
\Rightarrow \; & \color{purple}{-\text{Log}(1-e^{ix})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{inx}}{n!}} \\
&\text{(I couldn’t get the expansion from $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{C}$, but not the mainstream.)} \\
\Rightarrow \; & \color{red}{-\ln(1-\cos x - i \sin x) - i \arg(1-\cos x - i \sin x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos (nx) + i \sin(nx)}{n!}} \\
& \vdots
\end{align}
I couldn’t get whether we cound use the argument function in this series just like it was. Why does it work in such functions, and why is it the range $(-\pi, \pi]$?

Plus) Anyone who could explain also the expansion of series fron real to complex, I’d appreciate it. Thanks.

I think it's kind of reasonable, given that any log should be like a local inverse to the exponential, and angles clearly matter in the complex exponential.

Some decent explanations here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3835159/is-there-a-reason-why-textargz-behaves-like-a-logarithm?rq=1

Do you that complex numbers have a polar form: $x+iy=re^{i\theta}$?

This is a very broad question. It might help to narrow down to what you're most curious about. In particular, if you have an alternate formulation of a logarithm-like function F in mind, and you want to know why Log is used more than F, then please state what F is.

@geetha290krm Yeap, aware of that, but my question was that why the im part should be an acute angle.

We don't choose that to be the definition of $\log$.  We deduce it from the properties of $\exp$.  Study how $\exp$ behaves with imaginary values and it should start to make sense.  The range has to be restricted because $\exp$ is not one-to-one so it does not a unique inverse.

It does not have to an acute angle.  Try $\log(-1 + i)$.

Oh,,, then, how do we express argument in xy plane? For example above, taking an imaginary part of both, we get $-\arg(1-\cos x - i \sin x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {\sin x}{n!}$, and right-handed side can be expressed as a graph.
